# MVC3 - Client Side Validation Not Working After Implementing Service and Repository Layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I've been working on writing my first MVC3 application for a little while and I have encountered a bug that I am not able to resolve.  Client side validation does not appear to be working.  I keep getting: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

I have done a lot of research on this problem and have found quite a few people that have had similar issues whose solutions do not work for me.

My Web Config File Contains:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have setup data annotations on all of my Model classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Mike_Cottingham_Industries.Models
{
    public class Part
    {
        public Int32 PartID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Manufacturer Part Number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Manufacturer Part Number is required")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage="Manufacturer Part Number cannot exceed 50 characters")]
        public String ManufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Supplier Part Number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Supplier Part Number is required")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage="Supplier Part Number cannot exceed 50 characters")]
        public String SupplierPartNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Description is required")]
        [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage="Description cannot exceed 250 characters")]
        public String Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PartOrder> PartOrders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have the data validation scripts loaded in my views:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The only thing that I can think of that could be messing it up is the way that I have tried to make generic views.

I have created a generic 'Create' view:

```
<h2>Add</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm((string)@ViewBag.Action, (string)@ViewBag.ControllerName, FormMethod.Post, new { @class="niceform"})) {

    <fieldset class="edit_item">
        @Html.Partial("_Edit");
    </fieldset>
}

<div>   
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", (string)@ViewBag.ControllerName)" class="bt_green"><span class="bt_green_lft"></span><strong>Back to List</strong><span class="bt_green_r"></span></a>    
    <a href="#" class="bt_blue" onclick="$('.niceform').submit(); return false;"><span class="bt_blue_lft"></span><strong>Save</strong><span class="bt_blue_r"></span></a>    
</div>
```

And a partial that gets loaded by the generic view:

```
@model Mike_Cottingham_Industries.Models.Part     
@{
    ViewBag.Controller = "Part";
    ViewBag.Title = "Part";    
}
@if (ViewBag.IsEdit == true)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PartID)    
}
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<dl>
    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManufacturerPartNumber, "Manufacturer Part Number")</dt>
    <dd>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ManufacturerPartNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManufacturerPartNumber)</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierPartNumber)</dt>
    <dd>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupplierPartNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierPartNumber)</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)</dt>
    <dd>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)</dd>
</dl>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?  Views that do not use my 'generic' appear to be working fine.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what the issues was... I copied all of my code into a new project and everything worked fine.  Can't explain what was different.